# Data decimal to Binary

Tags: assembly, binary, integer-arithmetic

1. Convert X10 to Binary X2 ; You MUST determine and state exactly how many bits are necessary for the representation of X10 in binary. Round up the value for the number of bits necessary to represent X2 to the nearest multiple of 4 and express X2 in this number of bits with a space between each 4-bit group.

x10  58927634
I have converted x10 to x2

11100000110010101000010010

but I could not understand the part where it says round up the value for the number of bits necessary to represent X2 to the nearest multiple of 4, please I really need help I need only an explanation to solve this I don't need answer just explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to determine how many bits are needed to represent your decimal number - and then round it up so that it is a multiple of 4. Example:

```
Decimal = 19
Binary = 10011
Bits needed (minimum) = 5
Bits needed (rounded up) = 8
Final binary string = 0001 0011

Decimal = 58927634
Binary = 11100000110010101000010010
Bits needed (minimum) = 26
Bits needed (rounded up) = 28
Final binary string = 0011 1000 0011 0010 1010 0001 0010
```